# Automating client Side performance testing for fiddler

Tags: visual-studio, automated-tests, performance-testing, fiddler

We are using Fiddler to capture performance stats of the web pages and it is doing great but it's a manual effort every time. We want to automate the whole process for performance testing.

Raw workflow is as follows

1. Load  five times
2. Capture page load time and other metrics for each iteration
3. Compare the averages with defined thresholds

One solution I find so far is that we manually load URLs in fiddler, then export your session as `visual studio web test` format and use it with test cases. Again it involves some manual effort.

Another thought is that we configure fiddler in a way (scripting or Command line; didn't know yet) that it loads URLs automatically, do the processing, write everything in some log file. Afterwards our VS unit tests can read those logs files to read the metrics.

Is there anyway that we could automate the fiddler performance testing with Visual studio?